# How to reading out row from xml with elementTree using Python?

Tags: python, xml

Im new using Python, now I have a problem using `ElementTree` and read out values from an xml with this structure:

```
<entry number="47" date="2011-01-29">
    <name>Swedbank-taxe</name>
    <row account="1930" debit="0" credit="16712"/>
    <row account="8415" debit="1781" credit="0"/>
    <row account="2734" debit="14931" credit="0"/>
</entry>
<entry number="48" date="2011-01-29">
    <name>Agri - Calcium</name>
    <row account="1930" debit="0" credit="2000"/>
    <row account="1471" debit="400" credit="0"/>
    <row account="4370" debit="1600" credit="0"/>
</entry>
```

With this code I try to print out the content of every row with the `label="row"`:

```py
from tkinter import filedialog
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree as ET
xmltree = ET()
filval=filedialog.askopenfilename()
xmltree.parse(filval)
konton = xmltree.getiterator('row')
for i in konton:
    print (i.text)
```

But the only print out is `None`.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?
Also I would like to print out every row with `account="1930"`. In this case I would like a print out like this:

```py
1930
1930
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree as ET
xmltree = ET()
filval=filedialog.askopenfilename()
xmltree.parse(filval)
konton = xmltree.getiterator('row')
for i in konton:
    # remove this to print the account from every row
    if i.attrib['account'] == "1930":
        print (i.attrib['account'])
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing wrong is that you're trying to access an element attribute by looking at its text.

As explained in the [official ElementTree documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element) `Element.text` *contain any text found between the element tags*, which means that in `<row>this is the text in "text"</row>`.

If you want to access the attribute `account` of your element named `row`, you need to call [`Element.attrib`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib), *a dictionary containing the element’s attributes*:

```py
for i in xmltree.getiterator('row'):
    account = i.attrib['account']
    if account == '1930':
        print('account')
```

**Note:** The use of [`getiterator`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.getiterator) is deprecated since version 2.7 (or 3.2): Use method [`ElementTree.iter()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.iter) instead.

Comment: `i.get('account')` is safer if not all `<row>` elements have `'account'` attribute.

Comment: Yes using `get()` will also cover `<row>` without the `'account'` attribute, but I'm not sure if I'd like that behaviour, if all my row should have the attribute account I don't want to quiet down a possible typo in my xml, if on the other hand I'll accept having some `<row>` without the `'account'` attribute, then the use of `get()` is required. It's really an OP choice, I guess.

Comment: Thanx for helping :)! So instead of `for i in xmltree.getiterator('row'):` I should use `for i in xmltree.iter('row'):`?

Comment: @martin: You're welcome! And if your python version supports it then yes! *(I did a little mix up with the links, but they should be ok now)*

Comment: @martin: (unless you plan on portability with previous python versions)